# How to extract layers from two rasters based on a single parameter from each layer in QGIS

Tags: raster-calculator

I am working in QGIS with two WMS raster layers describing my city. One layer has a city planning. Other layer has ownership information of each plot.

I can see both layers combined with colours.

When I click a specific plot to identify a plot I have identification results:
[image]

As you can see on the right there is a parameter "GRUPA" with "uslugi" value.
Form another layer I would like to extract parameter" "WLASC" with "Miasto Poznan" value:
[image]

How can I create a layer with plots from one layer with a specific value from one raster and a specific value from another layer?

Comment: Raster calculator operations wont work on WMS data.

Comment: Is there a field/parameter that is the same on the 2 layers?  Like a feature ID or "name"?  You could write a small bit of code to extract the field and attach the value to the other layer.

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't the same ID.